# Difference between manifest claim mapping and PowerShell ADPolicy?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

Seems like there are two ways to define optional claims to be included in a token. You can do it, with some restrictions (which claims) using App registrations app manifest file as per: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims. However, New-AzureADPolicy can also do it and more - I was not able to add employeeId claim using the first method - but it applies to the ServicePrincipal, not the Application.Apart from what seems like a more restrictive claim list, what other differences are there between? Why are there two methods?

Comment: You used the `Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy` in your second method?

Comment: Yes, that one worked. Using 1st method did not work.